# Stretch View based on whether keyboard opened

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

In React Native, when the keyboard is closed, I want my `<View>` to be displayed on the full screen size, but whenever the keyboard is opened, I want it to be displayed only using the screen space that is visible to the user. How do I achieve that?

I've tried a couple of things, such as `<KeyboardAvoidingView>`, but didn't find a solution yet.

```
<View>
    ...
</View>
```

**Example**

[image: Example]

Comment: You still need to share the code.

Comment: what stylesheet you used ? better to using flex box in my opinion don't use fix size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated the y position using `onLayout`, the y position of another `<View>` with `bottom: 0`, saved them using states and subtracted the first from the latter to calculate the height using states. The state updates whenever the keyboard is opened or closed.

Answer (score 1):

post some code how do you construct current layout

in native apps for desired behavior you have to set in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in [HERE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-android-soft-input) some guide for react native and in [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust) you have some plugin which handles this